# Docker + PHP + RabbitMQ

Tags: php, docker, rabbitmq

I am trying to run a php program in a Docker container that listens for data from RabbitMQ.

Here's what I have done so far:

- Multi stage build with composer:1.9.3, php:7.4.3-cli
- Installed phpAmqpLib/php-amqplib

When I run the program I get  "Warning: require(./vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/src/myapp/test.php on line 3"

I ran "composer install" and I am still getting an error please assist if possible.

```
# PHP dependency manager
FROM composer:1.9.3 AS composer

FROM php:7.4.3-cli

# Copies dependency manager into PHP image
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

# Install RabbitMQ PHP client
RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq -y install \
    git \
    libzip-dev \
    unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
       sockets \
       zip \
    && composer require php-amqplib/php-amqplib \

    && composer install
# Copies files from a source directory into the containers filesystem
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
CMD ["php", "/usr/src/myapp/test.php"]
```

test.php

```php
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;

$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('messaging', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();
$channel->queue_declare('hello', false, false, false, false);

echo " [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C\n";

$callback = function ($msg) {
    echo ' [x] Received ', $msg->body, "\n";
};

$channel->basic_consume('hello', '', false, true, false, false, $callback);

while ($channel->is_consuming()) {
    $channel->wait();
}

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

Edit: Line 1 of test.php was previously using `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` and pointing to the current directory when in fact vendor was installed in the root directory.

Comment: `docker run -it yourimage:yourtag /bin/bash` should drop you into a shell in which you can inspect the container's filesystem, run test commands, what-have-you.

Comment: Please provide some info about how your PHP app looks like.

Comment: Thank you @Sammitch you helped point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Line 1 of test.php was previously using `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` and pointing to the current directory when in fact 'vendor' was installed in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

You command `COPY . /usr/src/myapp` execute after `composer require` or `composer install`.

```
# PHP dependency manager
FROM composer:1.9.3 AS composer

FROM php:7.4.3-cli

# Copies dependency manager into PHP image
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

# Copies files from a source directory into the containers filesystem
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp

# Install RabbitMQ PHP client
RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq -y install \
    git \
    libzip-dev \
    unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
       sockets \
       zip \
    && composer require php-amqplib/php-amqplib \
    && composer install

CMD ["php", "/usr/src/myapp/test.php"]
```